# How to increase column width size in datatables jquery

Tags: datatables

My datatable getting the data from a spring controller and populating in datatables.
Here the Message column in the datatable rows are displaying properly if the data contains spaces between words.

If the Message Column contains big words that doesn't contain spaces then the Column is overflowing and going after the border of the table.I want to set the column width for datatable so that it will break after some text and display properly.

```
<table id="user">
<thead>
<tr class="theader">

<th>Order Id</th>
<th>Message</th>
<th>Date Created</th>

</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
</tbody>
</table>

<script>                                        
$("#user").dataTable({
            "bFilter": false,
            "bAutoWidth": false,
            "bProcessing" : false,
            "bServerSide" : true,
            "sAjaxSource" : "./getLogDetails.cpm"
});
</script>
```

How can I set a column width for this datatable? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can change the width of a column like this:

```
$("#user").dataTable({
    "aoColumnDefs": [
        { "sWidth": "200px", "aTargets": [1] } // 1 would be the 2nd column
    ]
});
```

You could also use "sClass" to add a class to each cell in that column and style it in your CSS.

Note that this will work using the newest version of DataTables (1.10), but he changed the notation in 1.10 and you should use "DataTable", "columnDefs", "width", "className" and "targets" instead of the hungarian notation.